# heroku run rake db:create fails with Could not find gem 'pg..., but the database is mysql2 (not postgresql)

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, redmine

I receive the following error when I run `heroku run rake db:create`:

```
Running `rake db:create` attached to terminal... up, run.6027
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0.11.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

In the config/database.yml I'm using the default mysql2 database:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  ...
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  ...
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  ...
```

So I guess 'pg (>= 0.11.0) ruby' does not need to be installed. Am I wrong?

I'm using Windows XP. It is the first time I use Ruby.

---

**UPDATE 1**

I forgot to say `bundle install` finished correctly without errors.

On the other hand, Gemfile has the following code:

```
adapters.each do |adapter|
  case adapter
  when 'mysql2'
    gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
    gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  ...
  when /postgresql/
    gem "pg", ">= 0.11.0", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw]
    gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  ...
```

So again, I guess it should never enter in `when /postgresql/` when the command `heroku run rake db:create` is executed. Am I right?

Comment: Did you add a MySQL database to your Heroku application?

Comment: @NickVeys, I executed gem install `mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` and it finished correctly. I have the binaries of mysql-5.6.10, but I'm NOT running the database. Anyway, the error seems to be because it cannot install _pg (>= 0.11.0) ruby_

Comment: You're using Heroku, it's an application platform.  It doesn't have a MySQL database unless you add one.  Are you following a tutorial or something?  Heroku usually uses Postgres.

Comment: @NickVeys, thought the command `heroku run rake db:create` would create the mysql2 database (as the command ask to set config/database.yml first). Am I wrong? What that command do then? I'm following [this tutorial](http://tygertown.us/redmine-on-heroku/). I had to solve a lot of extra issues to reach that point though

Comment: It will initialize a database in a MySQL server, but you need a server to use first.  In that tutorial it says to [follow these instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb), have you done that?  I also don't see anywhere in that tutorial where it says to use `db:create`.

Comment: @NickVeys, I use [AppFog](https://www.appfog.com/) to deploy a [Grails](http://grails.org/) app. AppFog creates and configures the database automatically. I thought the database would be configured automatically in Heroku too. So, if I understood you well, the **database is independent to Heroku**, and I must to create and configure it. **ClearDB is an option to create it on the cloud**. Is it?

Comment: Yes, Heroku is just an application platform, you pick what database you want to use (if any). ClearDB is a provider of MySQL databases that is easy to set up with a Heroku app.

Comment: Thanks @NickVeys, you clarify me everything. So, if the error is because of that, feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion above...  This is a Heroku application and it needs a database configured or it is going to try and force Postgres as a dependency to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do **bundle install** before running the rake task for db creation and fulfill all gem dependencies. This is required even though you are using mysql and not postgres because the 'pg gem' is specified in the Gemfile and you have to make sure that all gem dependencies in your Gemfile are made available to your application by running the **bundle install** commmand.

As in your case you are using mysql, you do not require the 'pg gem' and can remove or comment it in the Gemfile.

Comment: Oh. I forgot to say **bundle install** finished correctly without errors. It think it should not be necessary to remove that line in Gemfile as I'm going to explain in **update 1**.